# Wie umgangssprachlich ist eigentlich "quasi"?

Tags: colloquial, latin

Mich beschäftigt immer wieder das Wort **quasi**. Von seiner offensichtlich lateinischen Herkunft her könnte man erwarten, dass es vorwiegend in gehobenen oder eher fachsprachlichen Zusammenhängen vorkommen würde, aber hin und wieder höre ich es in lässigen Gesprächen und umgangssprachlichen Situationen, und dann quasi (!) als die deutsche Version von *kind of* oder *pretty much* auf Englisch.
Wie förmlich ist **quasi** denn? Und fallen euch sonst noch Beispiele von lateinischen (oder griechischen) Wörtern ein, die meistens umgangssprachlich benutzt werden?

Comment: Hi Lenon! Willkommen hier auf german.SE! Wir versuchen hier, uns immer auf eine Frage auf einmal zu fokussieren. Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, geht es dir vor Allem um die Frage nach _quasi_, und die Frage nach anderen umgangssprachlichen Latinismen ist eher sekundär für dich? Wenn dir dieser zweite Aspekt wichtig ist, mach doch dazu eine zweite Frage auf. LG!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bevor ich auf die eigentliche Frage der Umgangssprachlichkeit von "quasi" eingehe, tun ein paar abgrenzende Worte Not. Insbesondere ist der Begriff "Umgangssprache" unscharf definiert und von ihm sagt [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umgangssprache) etwa:

> Im deutschen Sprachraum gibt es keine Standardvarietät, die als Umgangssprache dient.

Ohne das wissenschaftlichen Standards genügend belegen zu können, vermute ich allerdings, daß "Umgangssprache" - wenn überhaupt - nicht durch die Verwendung (bzw. Nichtverwendung) von bestimmten Wörtern definiert ist, sondern eher als kontextuelles Phänomen, bei dem sowohl Wortwahl wie auch syntaktische und grammatikalische Besonderheiten konstituierend wirken. Wikipedia meint (in demselben Lemma) dazu, es werde

> vor allem nach Sprachstil unterschieden[...].

Beispielsweise kommen die Wort "ist", "und", etc. durchaus in umgangssprachlichen Kontexten vor, ohne daß man aus deren Verwendung in Textwerken auf Umgangssprachlichkeit schließen könnte. Die Frage *ist dieses oder jenes Wort Umgangssprache* ist deshalb per se schon problematisch (und die Antwort darauf ein kategorisches *kommt darauf an*). Dasselbe könnte auch für "quasi" gelten und man könnte als Antwort etwa so formulieren:

> "quasi" ist ein Wort, das sowohl in der Umgangssprache wie auch in der Hochsprache Verwendung findet.

Andere Worte hingegen (etwa: "Haxe" statt "Bein"/"Fuß") konstituieren für sich schon einen umgangssprachlichen Kontext. Das ist allerdings bei "quasi" nicht der Fall.

Die von RHa etwähnten Worte "super" und "prima" sind Wörter, bei denen ebenjene Abhängigkeit vom Kontext deutlich sichtbar ist: "prima" kann geradezu gehobene Sprache signalisieren, auch wenn das *prima facie* nicht so erscheint. Das Wort "Super", für sich und in der Bedeutung von "gut" oder einer Treibstoffsorte mag ein Kolloquialismus sein, als Präfix in der Zusammensetzung "Superposition" oder "Supernova" hingegen ist es wohl eher Fachsprache, auch das Wort "superb" wird man kaum als Kolloquialismus bezeichnen.

Viel eher umgangssprachlich ist "optimal" - und zwar insbesondere dann, wenn es gesteigert wird:

> Können wir das nicht optimaler? Nein, das ist schon am optimalsten.

Auch das Wort "Trottoir" wurde hier erwähnt: wer zu dem Ding "Bürgersteig" sagt, wird in manchen Gegenden eher schräg angesehen, eben weil der *gehobene[...] Sprachgebrauch, der sich inzwischen weitgehend durchgesetzt hat*, sich lediglich in bestimmten Teilen des deutschen Spachgebiets durchgesetzt hat, während in anderen alles beim alten (und damit beim "Trottoir" ist. Aber das hängt wohl damit zusammen, daß speziell Sprecher der nord- und mitteldeutschen Sprachausprägungen dazu neigen, alles, was nicht ihrem Regiolekt entspricht, als "Dialekt" abzutun. *Nich wahr* ist dann "Hochdeutsch", "Semmel" hingegen "Dialekt".

Hingegen wird "Mille" in der Umgangssprache des mittel- und norddeutschen Sprachraums oft für einen (Geld-) Betrag verwendet, dessen Einheit tatsächlich "1000 (D-Mark, mittlerweile auch Euro)" ist. Im süddeutschen Sprachraum hingegen wird "Mille" für gewöhnlich als "Million" verstanden. Speziell in Ostösterreich wird hin und wieder (der Gebrauch scheint im Abnehmen bzw. Verschwinden begriffen zu sein) bei Geschwindigkeitsangaben auch "Kilo" für "100 km/h" verwendet.

> Sie haben mich mit (ein) Kilo fünzig geblitzt."

bedeutet dann "mit 150 km/h".

Im umgangssprachlichen Kontext wird auch das Wort *circa* verwendet - in jenen Gegenden, die ich kenne, viel häufiger, als "ungefähr", das eher in hochsprachlichen Kontexten verwendet wird.

Ein weiteres Wort, das umgangssprachlich Verwendung findet, ist *Zirkus*. In der Umgangssprache hat es nicht die normale Bedeutung ("fahrende Ansammlung von Attraktionen, die in Programmen organisiert zur Schau gestellt werden"), sondern in der Bedeutung "Aufregung aller Art".

> Hör' auf mit dem Zirkus.

Ist dann die Aufforderung, Ruhe zu geben und die (lautstark geäußerten) Beschwerden, Forderungen und dgl. einzustellen.

Answer (score 4):

Der Gebrauch von *quasi* ist auch in der Umgangssprache fest etabliert. Wer *quasi* benutzt, stellt damit kein höheres Bildungsniveau zur Schau.

Tatsächlich ist die Situation insofern paradox, als die "rein deutschen" Alternativen für *quasi* eher bildungssprachlich sind. Das gilt besonders für *gleichsam*. Wenn jemand dieses Wort mir gegenüber im Alltag benutzen würde, käme mir das seltsam vor. Für die Alternative *sozusagen* gilt das nicht im gleichen Maß, aber auch dieses Wort gehört nach meinem Gefühl zu einem höheren Register als *quasi*.

Warum das so ist, weiß ich nicht genau. Meine Vermutung ist, dass das damit zu tun hat, dass versucht wurde, sogenannte Fremdwörter durch Wörter deutscher Herkunft zu ersetzen, und dass das Bildungsbürgertum hier besonders eifrig war, während die Unterschicht weiter die "fremden" Wörter benutzt hat.

Das lässt sich bei einigen Wörtern französischer Herkunft beobachten, die im gehobenen Deutsch durch Wörter deutscher Herkunft ersetzt wurden. Ein Beispiel dafür ist *Trottoir*. In meiner Familie wurde dieses Wort in der Umgangssprache verwendet, während im gehobenen Sprachgebrauch, der sich inzwischen weitgehend durchgesetzt hat, vom *Bürgersteig* die Rede ist.

Noch ausgeprägter als bei *quasi* ist diese paradoxe Situation bei den Wörtern *super* und *prima* (eine super Sache, eine prima Sache). Diese Wörter sind ausgesprochen umgangssprachlich; im geschriebenen Deutsch werden sie eher vermieden.

Comment: Ich finde "Trottoir" kein gutes Beispiel. Da ist eher der regionale Unterschied/Dialekt das Entscheidende: https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r11-f4g/

Comment: Ich finde *a propos* ein ähnlich gutes Beispiel. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch höre ich es (und benutze es selbst) recht oft, aber lesen tue ich es sehr selten.

Answer (score 2):

Was mir noch fehlt ist folgende Beobachtung.

"quasi" ist für manche Menschen ein Füllwort geworden und hat spätestens dann seine Förmlichkeit verloren.
Mit Füllwort meine ich ein Wort das ohne viel nachzudenken überall eingebaut wird, wie auch "also", "sozusagen", "ich sag mal", "halt" und weitere.
Das wird halt quasi überall eingefügt :-) ohne dass es eine nähere Bedeutung hat und höchstens nervt, wenn man es übertreibt.

Wie auch das erwähnte "kind of" im englischsprachigen. Es gibt Videos die kann man sich vor lauter "then I do kind of this... look this is kind of funny... oh here we have kind of a problem..." nicht mehr ansehen.
Auch das ist völlig bedeutungslos und ist aus reiner Gewohnheit da. Oder vielleicht noch weil es cooler klingen soll, es aber nicht tut.

Answer (score 1):

Über die Gründe kann ich hier nur spekulieren. Aber ich fürchte, mehr werden wir hier nicht bekommen.

Ich denke, dass nicht das Wort selbst, sondern seine Bedeutung in das Register der Umgangssprache fällt. Der Ausdruck markiert Ungenauigkeit in der Aussage. Ungenaue Aussagen dürften in der Umgangssprache häufiger anzutreffen sein als in (sogenannten) gehobenen Registern. *quasi* wird daher mit einem eher laxen, umgangssprachlichen Sprachgebrauch assoziiert.

Das trifft in meinen Augen auch auf die von dir angesprochenen englischen Ausdrücke *kind of* und *pretty much* zu, ebenso auch auf das deutsche *sozusagen*.

Das von RHa angesprochene bedeutungsgleiche *gleichsam* sticht nur deshalb heraus, weil es enorm selten ist und daher fast schon gestelzt wirkt.